# python filter out pseudo-duplicates by merging the differing values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filtering

I have a list of dictionaries with eight keys and I want to select those entries which differ in just one key and merge those. A tiny example:

```
listWithDups = [{'name1': 'aaa', 'len1': 3, 'site1': 'a', 'name2': 'zzzz', 'len2': 4, 'site2': 'z', 'retailer': 'ret1', 'buffer': 'buff1'},
                {'name1': 'bbb', 'len1': 3, 'site1': 'b', 'name2': 'zzzz', 'len2': 4, 'site2': 'z', 'retailer': 'ret1', 'buffer': 'buff1'},
                {'name1': 'aaa', 'len1': 3, 'site1': 'a', 'name2': 'zzzz', 'len2': 4, 'site2': 'z', 'retailer': 'ret1', 'buffer': 'buff2'}]
```

The first and the last list entry just differ in the key 'buffer' and as a result I want a list of dictionaries like:

```
listWithoutDups = [{'name1': 'aaa', 'len1': 3, 'site1': 'a', 'name2': 'zzzz', 'len2': 4, 'site2': 'z', 'retailer': 'ret1', 'buffer': 'buff1 / buff2'},
                   {'name1': 'bbb', 'len1': 3, 'site1': 'b', 'name2': 'zzzz', 'len2': 4, 'site2': 'z', 'retailer': 'ret1', 'buffer': 'buff1'}]
```

I wanted to sort the list of dictionaries by both name identifier and check each two nearby dictionaries if they differ in this name-combination if they do I would write the first dictionary in a new list and iterate through the whole list else I would add one of the duplicated dictionaries merging the buffer keys with a string concatenation and proceed with the rest of the list. Is there any short way to do this task without setting up more than one list of dictionaries? And how do I compare the nearby elements by more than one key?

I hope my description is not too confusing :/

Comment: the only difference is in buffer? Or you want to detect differences in other keys too?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is buffer, so entries where the other keys are identical should be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that only buffer is different, and using only 2 other keys:

```
def merge_buffers(dupes):
    merged = {}
    for item in dupes:
        # create tuple key, so all entries with same key will be appended here
        key = (item['name1'], item['len1'])
        if not key in merged:
            merged[key] = []
        merged[key].append(item['buffer'])
    return merged
```

This is idea, extend to more keys as exercise to the reader.

Result is dict, key is your unique `name1`/`len1`, value is list of all buffers found for this combination of other keys.

So to convert it back to list of dictionaries:

```
unduped_dict = merge_buffers(dupes)
unduped_list = []
for key in unduped_dict:
    item = {'name1': key[0], 'len1': key[1], 'buffer': '/'.join(unduped_dict[key]) }
    unduped_list.append( item )
```

In Python, the more dictionaries you use, the more pythonic is your solution!

Comment: Well first of all, a big thx for your solution! It does what I want to :) there are 2 typos in your code, a missing parentheses behind merged[key].append(item['buffer'] and you missed a 's' in you function call on the second code snippet :) just for my understanding.. the outcome of your merged_buffers() function is one dictionary?

Comment: @heiiRa You are right. I just typed it without testing, just to check if you are reading carefully while I am doing your homework.